# How can you "explode" an array in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'd like to "explode" an array in Ruby in order to do a fast variable assignment i.e.

```
a, b = ['first_var', 'second_var']
```

Is this possible? I've looked through the array docs and can't find anything that seems to offer this but it seems Rubyish...

Comment: The code you've written should work exactly as you've written it. What exactly are you looking for? What is it you think is wrong with the code you've posted?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking; the snippet you wrote works as-is.

Comment: Ahh, not quite sure why that passed me by. Nice to see I've got an intuitive grasp of the language though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works as you would expect. Note that you can use `*` to slurp up extra right hand side elements, whereas extra elements on the left hand side will be set to `nil`:

```
>> range = *1..10 #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>> a, b = range #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>> [a, b] #=> [1, 2]
>> a, *b = range #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>> b #=> [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>> a, b, c = 1,2 #=> [1, 2]
>> c #=> nil
```